# RedirectToAction redirects wrong with Other namespaces asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routetable

I wrote my routes like this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AdminECommerce",
    url: "Admin/ECommerce/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new []{ "AdminEcommerce.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ECommerce",
    url: "ECommerce/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new []{ "Ecommerce.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "User",
    url: "Plugin/User/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new []{ "User.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "UserRegistration",
    url: "Plugin/UserRegistration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new []{ "UserRegistration.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When I want to use `RedirectToAction` from one Action to other Action in the same Controller It Redirects Somewhere else.

For Example, I want it to redirect me to

```
Plugin/UserRegistration/Register/Register
```

But,It Sends me to

```
Admin/ECommerce/Register/Register
```

I Have to mention that my controllers are in other libraries.

What is wrong with my code?

Update: Controller `Registration`

```
public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.securityQuestions = _dataRepository.GetContext().User_SecurityQuestion;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(User_User model, FormCollection collection)
    {

        try
        {
            // register new user 
              ...
            return RedirectToAction("Register");
        }
        catch
        {
            // making error messages 
              ...
            return RedirectToAction("Register");
        }
```

I also tried this,

```
return RedirectToAction("Register","Registration");
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Show your controller code for redirecting

Comment: I see that route `AdminECommerce` executed first rather than `UserRegistration` by top-down route order, if they're in areas you may add area parameter into `defaults` to distinguish between them.

Comment: I don't have areas in my project ,Just separate class libraries for every part of my project.

Comment: @AliVahidi Which version of mvc you are using ?

Comment: I'm using mvc 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC recognizes these two routes, as the same by UriTemplate

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AdminECommerce",
    url: "Admin/ECommerce/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new []{ "AdminEcommerce.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "UserRegistration",
    url: "Plugin/UserRegistration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new []{ "UserRegistration.Controllers" }
);
```

MVC reads Route table from top to bottom to match requested Url with UriTemplate. So, in this case it will select the first template.

Try to use [RedirectToRoute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992853(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
return RedirectToRoute("Registration", new 
{ 
    controller = "Registration", 
    action = "Register"
});
```

Comment: for first paramter I replaced "Registration" with "UserRegistration" and now it works well,
Thanks.

Comment: Glad to have been of help :)

Comment: I can confirm that this is true. I had the same problem. The easiest way was to not have the same names for Action methods and Class names. But anyway, i hope that this will be improved somehow if possible. :/ The second option is to use a redirect to url instead of redirectToAction like this: `Redirect("http://www.google.com/")`.